# Do we need a list of questions/answers that can be ChemDraw'd?

Tags: discussion

A well-maintained and timely-update list of questions and answers with hand drawn structures will provide incentives to new users who are looking to earn some reputation (and some badges). Further more, it would make the posts look *cleaner*.

## Pros:

- Improves legibility of *poorly* hand-drawn structures.
- It would take the load off a few *old* users who are currently doing this task.
- Increase participation of new users.

## Cons:

- Homepage is likely to be flooded with old posts.

Any thoughts, suggestions or ideas? Yay or nay?

Comment: I think there are well over 5,000 posts that could be Chemdraw'd, so all of them, nay. If you localize a search to Chemdraw only a portion of them, however, it'd be yay.

Comment: Yay. I say to put together a list and I'll do some. We don't have to do them all at once, just a few here and there.

Comment: Surely, "ChemDrawn"?

Comment: @DavidRicherby MarvinSketch'd structures will work as well.

Comment: @DavidRicherby or "ChemDoodle'd" as well

Comment: If this happens (and I sure hope it does), I hope that a computer-parsable representation of the molecules drawn can be provided in the answer when they are updated.  Perhaps SMILES for the shown molecule could be in the alt-text for the ChemDraw image?  Just imagine how cool it would be to be able to execute structure queries on chem.se data!

Comment: @CurtF. How about something like [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/766/11367)?

Comment: I like it.  Looks good.

Comment: Rolled back the edit. Laying in all of this site-wide would be a herculean task,  images with multiple structures would be terribly awkward to annotate, and there are many other more useful things that could be done with the time it'd take to implement.

Answer (score 5):

This is intended to be a CW list of all such questions, so that any person can go through it in their free time and edit things out. To limit the scope of this list:

1. **a ChemDrawable question** is a question that has image(s) of **hand-drawn** reaction(s)/molecule(s) ([example](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/revisions/10774/6)). This also includes **poor pictures** of systematically-drawn reaction(s)/molecules(s) **taken from a book.** ([example](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/revisions/73379/1))
2. **Aim** is to **replace these images** with an image of the corresponding reaction(s)/molecule(s) **generated** by specialized software like ChemDraw/MarvinSketch/ChemDoodle/ChemSketch/etc. This is an [example](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/70532/5026) of a valid image.

Also, please remember from this [meta post](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3014/editing-presentation-of-chemical-structures-to-chemdraw-or-not-to-chemdraw):

> **There's no need to make this ("editing of chemical structures") compulsory.**  (*my emphasis*) I don't think it would achieve anything. Producing these images is time-consuming and regulars here are busy in real life, I do not want to feel compelled to edit an old question whenever I see a hand-drawn mechanism.

### **The list:**

<sup>(in no particular order)</sup>

1. [Lewis Structure on (CH3)2NO?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31757/lewis-structure-on-ch32no)
2. [Mechanism of sulfur trioxide reaction with water to make sulfuric acid](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/10774/402)
3. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/72948/43942
4. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/64796/43942
5. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/90950/5026
6. [Finding number of stereoisomers of cyclobutane-1,2,3,4-tetracarboxylic acid?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/68892/5026)
7. [Reaction of bicyclic diol with periodic acid](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86642/5026)
8. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/67080/5026
9. [Mechanism for synthesising azetidine](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/40163/5026)
10. [What is the major product in the reaction of 2,3-dichlorobutane with sodium amide in liquid ammonia?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/48347/5026)
11. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/18519/5026
12. [Through bond interaction in biradical dioxo compound and its correlation diagram](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/32968/5026)

Comment: No one's going to make these, are they?

Comment: @AvnishKabaj Someday if I find time I might make some myself. Or maybe another user will come along. Though it's definitely helpful to have a list.

Comment: It was rhetorical :P .